# Error al trocear un programa c++ en .h, .cpp y main.cpp ficheros

Tags: c++

He troceado un programa `moyenne.cpp` que hace la media de un vector de calificaciónes c++ en tres : `main.cpp`, `moyenne.cpp` y `moyenne.h`.

Ya funciona el fichero solo, pero hoy me dice el programa cuando hizo `g++ main.cpp -o main` que :

```
In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x196): undefined reference to `moyenne(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&)'
```

Sin embargo utiliso en `main.cpp`

```
#ifndef MOYENNE_H_INCLUDED
#define MOYENNE_H_INCLUDED

#include<vector>

double moyenne(std::vector<double>const& tableau);
```

y lo mismo "includes" en moyenne.cpp.

#### actualización

Cuando hizo `g++ moyenne.cpp -o moyenne` tengo un error similar :

```
$ g++ moyenne.cpp -o moyenne
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Entonces no entiendo donde esta esta undefined reference ...

Comment: ¿ Orden exacta que usas para generar el ejecutable ?

Comment: `undefined reference` es que no encuentra el **cuerpo** de la función `moyenne`, te falta compilar o añadir a tu proyecto el archivo `moneye.cpp`.

Comment: estaba por editar el titulo, para cambiar `programo` por `programa` pero vi que usted emplea ese termino varia veces en la pregunta, asi que no se si, usted llama a programa, por programo, quizas fue un error o es que asi tambien se acostumbra a escribir. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel es que Marine1 es francés; poco a poco, va mejorando su español. No seas muy severo :-)

Comment: @Trauma mi intencion no fue el ser severo, todo lo contrario, le comente por si tenia que cambiarlo y no hacerlo yo directamente pues no sabia si en algun pais, quizas se decia asi, quien sabe, y si fue un error como comentas que es frances, seguro que asi aprende mas rapido, si lo modifica el OP, por otro lado, es posible que escriba español mejor que yo. Saludos

Comment: @Trauma Cualquier sea el orden siempre me da este tipo de error : `undefined reference to...`

Comment: Puede que [esta guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal) te ayude a entender el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes **2** archivos fuente, así que has de usar opciones *distintas* para generar el ejecutable:

```
g++ -c moyenne.cpp -o moyenne
```

Observa el `-c`. Con esto, le decimos al compilador que **no es un ejecutable final, sino un archivo objeto**.

Para generar el ejecutable final, **después** de la orden anterior, hacemos

```
g++ -o test main.c moyenne.o
```

Al usar varios archivos, cada uno de ellos es un *objeto* independiente, pero, si no se lo indicamos, el compilador **buscará** `main( )` en cualquier archivo fuente que le digamos.

Además, cada archivo objeto **no tiene conocimiento real** de lo que hay en otros. Eso es una operación aparte de compilar, llamada **enlazado** (link). Es durante este *enlazado* que se buscan las referencias a las funciones, y se establecen los punteros adecuados.