# Duda compilar archivo cpp y .h

Tags: c++, atom-editor

Buenas a todos, veréis, tengo los siguientes archivos:

- **main.cpp** donde se usa dicha clase y funciones de ellas.
- **Tiempo.cpp:** con definiciones de funciones de la clase
- **Tiempo.h:** con la clase, funciones miembros + miembro de datos.

Me gustaría compilarlos todos, he leído bastante de crear objetos de esos archivos, pero aun así no puedo compilarlos.
¿Alguien me podría explicar cómo compilarlos todos?
Según he leído [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122208/error-definiciones-multiples-cpp) y [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62705/error-al-trocear-un-programa-c-en-h-cpp-y-main-cpp-ficheros) necesitaría crear el objeto de main, crear archivo objeto de Tiempo y luego enlazar main con Tiempo, entonces he probado por ejemplo esta línea:

```
g++ -c Tiempo.cpp -o Tiempo
```

Pero no me funciona, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

EDITO: Amplío datos: he probado también con: gcc -c Tiempo.cpp o gcc -c main.cpp pero me muestra el mismo fallo, haga lo que haga (genere código objeto o cualquier otra cosa).

```
./Tiempo.h:1:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000><U+0000>...

./Tiempo.h:1:2: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<CF><FA><ED><FE><U+0007><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001><U+0003><U+0000><U+0000>...
```

y así sucesivamente...

Comment: ¿Has probado separando los pasos? Primero generar los objetos (`.o`) y después enlazando `g++ -o ejecutable main.o tiempo.o`

Comment: He ampliado los datos en la edición, pero me sigue saliendo ese mismo dichoso mensaje. Gracias @Paula_plus_plus

Comment: Tiene pinta de que hay caracteres extraños al inicio del fichero... verifica la codificación del fichero... debería ser o ASCII puro o UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando compilas un programa que tiene varios ficheros, puedes hacerlo de varias formas. Para este caso, quiza la opción mas simple es compilar directamente todos los cpps juntos en el ejecutable final:

```
g++ Tiempo.cpp main.cpp -o Tiempo
```

El problema que pareces tener no tiene que ver con los comandos en si mismos, sino con el encoding del fichero .h. Te sugeriría que mirases que tipo de fichero es. En linux lo puedes hacer a través del comando file.

```
file Tiempo.h
```

Igual esto te da alguna pista.